# How to update a column in the same table from a SELECT using sybase

Tags: database, sybase

I am trying to update column in the same table where my SELECT below is returning the results. The name of the column to update is ID with 'AfterString' result from the select.

My select which returns the data  I want in 'AfterString' field:

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(CODE,len(CODE)-charindex('@',CODE)) as AfterString
FROM dbo.LOG
WHERE charindex('@',CODE)<>0
```

I am not sure how to map it row to its correspondent row in the same table.

Comment: are you trying to update the same row or a different row?  if trying to update a different row, what is the `where` clause to locate the other row?

Comment: I am trying to  update the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the same exact row where the `AfterString` data is coming from:

```
update dbo.LOG
set    ID = RIGHT(CODE,len(CODE)-charindex('@',CODE))
where  charindex('@',CODE)<>0
```